# Unmarshalling nested collection via @XmlPath MOXy annotation

Tags: java, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

Given the following XML structure:

```
<root>
  <data>x</data>
  <details>
    <some_other_element>...</some_other_element>
    <collection>
      <element><a>1</a></element>
      <element><a>2</a></element>
      <element><a>3</a></element>
    <collection>
  </details>
</root>
```

How would I unmarshal this into a mostly flat POJO using MOXy? I tried this approach (getters and setters left out for brevity):

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
class Root {
  @XmlElement
  private String data;

  @XmlElement
  @XmlPath("details/some_other_element")
  private String someOtherElement;

  @XmlPath("details")
  @XmlElementWrapper(name = "collection")
  @XmlElement(name = "element")
  private Collection<Element> elements;
}

class Element {
  @XmlElement
  private String a;
}
```

Unfortunately, this just adds a single uninitialized to the `elements` collection. I'd like to avoid having to declare a `Details` class (which does indeed work) as that breaks the other `@XmlPath` mappings for elements below `<details>`.

I have verified that MOXy is actually loaded (as declared in the jaxb.properties).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the wrapping tag and the element to the `@XmlPath` instead of using `@XmlElementWrapper`:

```
@XmlPath("details/collection/element")
@XmlElement(name = "element")
private Collection<Element> elements;
```

I think you can even keep the `@XmlElementWrapper` annotation in case of future change of the jaxb provider.

---

Below is the minimal annotations your require for your use case:

```
package forum11153599;

import java.util.Collection;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement
class Root {
    @XmlElement
    private String data;

    @XmlPath("details/some_other_element/text()")
    private String someOtherElement;

    @XmlPath("details/collection/element")
    private Collection<Element> elements;

}
```

Comment: +1 - I'm the MOXy lead and your answer is correct.  I hope you don't mind I added an example of what the `Root` class could look like.

Comment: Excellent, works like a charm (although I am quite certain that I also tried this variant before ;-) )!